# How do i can data from my custom form to a custom table

Tags: forms, table

Hi i am struggling to find the correct code i need to insert the values from a custom form to a custom table i have already created.
My form is as below

#### Add a activity

Supervisor:

Description

Date

---

and i have already created the table in wordpress to accept these fields.
the table is called wpd_activity_record
and has the following columns
name - varchar
description - varchar
date - Date

can anyone help me please to get me going with this?
cheers Kevin

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code used to create the template? If possible, also post the table you would like to create with examples where the data should go.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to create the form, i have created the table already, it has 3 columns, name [varchar], description [varchar] and date [date]. i am missing the code to include that allows the from to upload the values in the fields to the table please.

`<form method = "post" action = "">
       <h3>Add a activity</h3> 
      <p style="font-weight:bold;" label for="supervisor">Supervisor:</label> 
         <input type="text" name="supervisor"/>
      </p>
      <p style="font-weight:bold;" label for="description">Description</label>
         <input type="text" name="description"/>
      </p>
      <p style="font-weight:bold;" label for="date">Date</label>
         <input id="date" type="date" name="date"/>
     </p>
      <hr> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="activity_submit"/> 
</form>
</br>`

The table is called wpdb_activity_record ,and image of which is below.

[image: this is the table in the db that i have created]